# How to redirect a URL to the same URL with port number inserted dynamically

Tags: angularjs, html, go

For example:

Here the main intension is to hide the port number in the url.
User should see the http://myproject.com/home/projects in the address bar on click of a button in webpage but it should dynamically redirect to the url http://myproject.com:portnumber/home/projects

I am using angular js and html for frontend and golang as backend.

What are the feasible ways to achieve above redirection either in golang or angular js?

Comment: If you "dynamically redirect", the port will be visible in the address bar. If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, you need to set up a proxy in your web server.

Comment: As @Blurp mentioned a better way to handle this is to use a proxy. You could use caddy server for this which is easy to understand and configure IMO. https://caddyserver.com/docs/proxy

Answer (score 0):

you have `*http.Request` in your handle function and you can get your current host with `*http.Request.URL.Host` you get your domain and port that requested to your webserver.

```
func handler(r *http.Request, response http.Response) {
    println(r.URL.Host)
}
```